# Find a $\delta >0$ such that if $x< \delta $, then $|\frac{1}{x+1}-1|<0.05$.

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

Could someone explain something to me about the following question?

> Find a $\delta >0$ such that if $|x|< \delta $, then $|\frac{1}{x+1}-1|<0.05$.

I got the inequality $-0.0476\leq x\leq 0.0526$, and the textbook chose $\delta = 0.0476$. Could someone please explain why they chose this $\delta$? Why not $\delta = -0.0476$? Would it be too big since then it would be like $0.04997<0.05$?

Comment: Becase $\delta$ is assumed to be positive.  So they chose $\delta = \min (|-0.0476|, |0.0526|)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why not δ=−0.0476?

Because that is a negative number.

And $|\frac 1{x+1} -1| < -0.0476 < 0$ will *never* happen.

And the didn't chose $\delta = 0.0526$ because that is too big/not strict enough.

The number $x = -0.05$ is such that $|x|< 0.0526$ but

$|\frac 1{x+1} - 1| = |\frac 1{-.05+1} -1| = |\frac 1{.95} - 1| = |1.0526315789473684210526315789474 - 1| = .0526315789473684210526315789474 > .05$.

If we have $-0.0476 < x < 0.0526$ then we have *CAN'T* have $x < -0.0476$, we must choose $\delta$ to be the MINIMUM of $|-0.0476|$ and $|0.0526|$.

Now you may be saying: but then we are losing all the $0.476 < x < 0.0526$ for which $x$ would be okay.  But that's okay, we don't need find *all* possible $x$.  Just a *range* of $x$ where $|\frac 1{x+1} - 1|$ *must* be less than $.05$.  Not *could* be (as $0.476 < x < 0.0526$ could be) but *must* be (as $-0.0526< x < -0.0476$) *can't* be.

Answer (score 2):

Note that to fulfill the condition obtained

$$-0.0476\leq x\leq 0.0526$$

we need to choose

$$\delta=\min\{0.0476,0.0526\}>0$$

such that for

$$|x|<\delta\implies -0.0476\leq x\leq 0.0526$$

indeed recall that

$$|x|<\delta\iff -\delta <x<\delta$$

Answer (score 2):

You just have to find *a* $\delta$,
not the best one.
At least that is what you wrote.

$|\dfrac{1}{x+1}-1|
=|\dfrac{1-(x+1)}{x+1}|
=|\dfrac{x}{x+1}|
$,
so if
$|x| < \frac12$,
$|\dfrac{1}{x+1}-1|
\lt \dfrac{|x|}{\frac12}
=2|x|
$.

Therefore,
to make
$|\dfrac{1}{x+1}-1|
\lt .05$,
it is sufficient to make
$2|x| < .05$
or
$|x| < .025$.

This is not the best,
but it will do.
If the problem wants
the largest bound,
it should say so.

Answer (score 1):

$$|x|\le 0.0476 \implies -0.0476\leq x\leq 0.0476 \implies-0.0476\leq x\leq 0.0526 $$